# Cannot even ping my WAN ip outside LAN!

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables, lan

I want to set up my computer as an SSH server on WAN (so I can access it from everywhere). I set up DMZ with my router and installed sshd, and *I can connect and log in to it from within my LAN* using my external IP (100XX.XX.XXX).

When I try it on another wireless network (or even mobile data), I can't even ping it! Pinging 100.XX.XX.XXX just doesn't respond. I Googled it and  found that it may be a firewall issue. My only firewall is iptables, which I disabled with the command `sudo ufw disable`. Iptables seems disabled, but I can't still ping my server's IP address!

- Ipconfig rules - I know I disabled it:

  ```
  $ sudo iptables -S
  -P INPUT ACCEPT
  -P FORWARD ACCEPT
  -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
  ```
- Connecting through ssh on my computer using the WAN IP—I cannot do this outside my LAN or with mobile data:

  ```
  $ ssh acer@1
  The authenticity of host '100.XX.XX.XX' can't be established.
  ECDSA key fingerprint is    SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
  ```

Thanks

Comment: EDIT: wrong typing: I meant I CAN'T ping my server's WAN IP outside my LAN

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about that. Please [edit] your question to correct it instead of posting a comment.

Comment: @terdon thanks! I didn't knew about this feature. Pratically I cannot connect to my home computer (my ssh server) from anywhere excepting my home network (even if I use my external IP address). I cannot even pinging it! What could be the issue? I just googled a few days but looks like nobody had my issue - asked on IRC, researching on Google, reading about DMZ...

Comment: put as much detail as possible into your question. Specifically, explain how you set up your router to allow this. If you haven't done anything in your router settings, what you describe is normal.

Comment: Ok. I want to create an SSH server that I can access by everywhere, store data, update my computer ecc... I decided that the computer I am writing to you right now would me my server. At first I installed sshd on my laptop on my Arch Linux partition (which I will use for ssh). After that I enabled UPnP on my router to allow traffic on port 22 to my laptop. That however didn't dorked. I thinked that was a firewall issue and I should disabled it. However firewall was already disabled (on my router). So I disabled IPTABLES. Still didn't worked.

Comment: Please edit your question and add all this, comments are easy to miss. You still haven't explained if you've opened the ports in your router or redirected them to the right machine in your Lan. Finally, if you are using Arch, this is off topic here. We only deal with Ubuntu. You should ask on [Unix.se]  or [su]. And if you haven't configured your router, certainly on [su].

Comment: Then i disabled UPnP and enabled DMZ and... surprise! It worked! I could connect to a WAN IP address that was mine! Using connectbot from my phone allowed me to connect to my home computer using my WAN IP. When I went to school, however, I couldn't connect to my computer. Even ping was useless... The same was with mobile data :(. I thought that my computer was powered off, but when I went back home... I could connect! (because I was on the same wireless network). So, when I am in the same LAN with my computer, I can connect to both my LAN and WAN IP address. Otherwise, I can't connect to it :(

Comment: @terdon sorry I was out of avaliable characters

Comment: If that obfuscated address is in the 100.64.0.0/10 range, then it is not a publicly routable IP address.  Your ISP is using carrier-grade NAT.

Comment: Yes, actually the address I was using is 100.96.31.103! I could not figured out why I could not connect outside my LAN... Thanks! However, how can I connect to my computer then? Trying *ssh -l $user $ROUTERS_IP_ADDRESS* just does not respond... Any idea about how can I fix it? I CAN ping my router actually, but I cannot connect to my server with neither DMZ nor UPnP enabled - port forwarding is in UPnP